# How to check properly Db connection are opened or closed in java webapplication

Tags: java-melody

Is any way tool or any machines to find out whether DatabaseConnections are properly opened or closed in real time java web application.

```
Is it suggestable to use javamelody related jar file?
```

Thanks and Regards,
Raju.

Comment: What DatabaseConnectios? What is *properly*?

Comment: Oracle Database and having multiple connections in the application